# How to wait for XHR to 3rd party API in Cypress?

Tags: testing, cypress

I have a SPA application that talks with API that deployed on another server. For example, when I click a Submit button it sends XHR request to it API, and I need to wait for a response to check it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `cypress/support/commands.js`:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('manageMyApiRequests', () => {
    cy.route('/URL/Of/api/I/Want/To/wait/For').as('myApi') 
});
```

Then in your test or before each call:

```
cy.server();
cy.manageMyApiRequests();
```

Then where-ever you want to wait for that api response just do:

```
cy.wait('@myApi');
```

The same can also be acheived without the first cypress command `manageMyApiRequests` but I suggest you use this for better organization of your tests and then later you can also add more apis to the same function.

FYI you can also use `.then()` it if you want to check something within the response:

```
cy.wait('@myApi').then((xhr) => {
    // we can now access the low level xhr
    // that contains the request body,
    // response body, status, etc
});
```

Comment: I already tried, but it did not work. It says `No request ever occurred.` (yes, I'm sure that request has been sent).

Comment: @Ivan Did you send the request using cypress api or was it generated by clicking on a button?

Comment: If you send api manually using cypress then this wait method will not work. If you click on a button and a request is sent to the server then this method should work. Make sure that the URL you are using is correct HINT: check your baseurl as well.

Comment: Yeah, my app is sending it(not cypress). I tried both, with full URL, and with wildcards like this: `**/registration/confirmation`. Both did not work

Comment: Can you post the error screen-shot and whatever concrete info about the error you can post. Secondly check if this method in my answer works for any other api request other than the one you are checking (ideally on a different website). Last but not least which cypress version you are using?